# Can I test an app on an iOS device belonging to someone who lives in another part of the world?

Tags: ios, testflight

I have finished working on an iOS app that I would like to give some friends of mine to test on their devices before submitting it to the app store.  However, they live in another parts of the world, and am unable to get a hold of their respective devices.  Is there a way for me to use their UDID and generate an .ipa file to send them to test on their device via email, without them having to physically provide me with their actual device?

I have heard of TestFlight as a possible solution, but can it be used for a device that is located in another part of the world, and I simply have the UDID to work with?  Please bear in mind that the people whom I wish to have test my app are NOT iOS developers, and are therefore NOT registered with Apple's Developer program.  Can it still be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, TestFlight is exactly the type of service you would use to do this easily with non-developer testers. They will be able to click a link in the e-mail and it will install your app on their phone. It doesn't matter where they are physically located as long as you add their UDIDs to your TestFlight and Apple Developer account.

Answer (score 3):

For that you have to create new device in your iOS Provisioning Portal with your friends UDID. And then in your *Provisioning Portal > Provisioning > Distribution > Your provisioning profile* and edit your currant distribution profile and add newly created divice in that distribution profile. than create ad hoc distribution IPA with this new provisioning profile. And, taadaa, this IPA will run on your friends iPhone.

Here is the screenshot for distribution certificate.

[image]

[image]

Use this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wAdV16nRLp8) to create distribution profile and IPA for ad-hoc.

It is same as we are giving our app to client for review.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed solution, but I unfortunately already awarded the correct answer to someone else (who was the first to reply).  I am grateful to you for taking the time to provide the screenshots, as well as for providing me the link to the video :-)  Take care, and all the best!

Answer (score 0):

Testflight allows you to do so. ALl you need to do is to register their UDID in your account and send them a link to download the app. Then you send your applications through the account and they will receive an email to download the app.

Hope this helps..